# Two apps disagree on sqllite3 DATEFIELDs -- which is correct?

Tags: django, sqlite, datetime

I am running into an incompatibility in the handling of the **sqllite3 DATEFIELD** between **Digikam (photo management software)** and **Django (a python web framework)**. I encountered the problem because I'm trying to write a Django application which will provide a webpage interface to my photo collection based on my Digikam database.

The database was created by Digikam and all of the DATEFIELDS are in this format (using SQLite Database Browser to view the tables):

```
**2011-02-06T19:06:28**
```

When Django stores dates (using the Django DateTime field), the format in the database is:

```
**2011-03-04 00:24:07.013620**
```

Django chokes whenever it encounters the date/times created by Digikam:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py in typecast_date(s)
     58 
     59 def typecast_date(s):
---> 60     return s and datetime.date(*map(int, s.split('-'))) or None # returns None if s is null
     61 
     62 def typecast_time(s): # does NOT store time zone information

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '03T15:53:14'
```

So, this brings up a few questions:

1. Which of these date formats is valid?
2. Doesn't sqllite validate datetime input?
3. Is there an easy way to get Django to happily read the Digikam format dates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this exact same frustration. I ended up writing the following monkey patch in my models.py which "solved" the problem for me:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------                                                       
# Monkeypatch date parser to be friendly with Digikam SQLite                                                          
# -------------------------------------------------------------                                                       

import django.db.backends.util                                                                                        
orig_typecast_date = django.db.backends.util.typecast_date                                                            
def monkeypatch_typecast_date(s):                                                                                     
    if s and 'T' in s:                                                                                                
        s = s[:s.find('T')]                                                                                           
    return orig_typecast_date(s)                                                                                      
django.db.backends.util.typecast_date = monkeypatch_typecast_date
```

Comment: Yep, tim, that's almost identical to what I ended up doing, see my diff here: http://code.google.com/p/django-digikam/source/browse/trunk/django_patches/dKtimestamp.diff

Can I ask what you're doing this for? Want to join forces for further work on django - digikam integration?

Comment: I was going to ask you the same question, but forgot. I suspect given the software in question the answer probably won't be a surprise: expose digikam database directly to the web. I have planned on open sourcing my code, though I fear it's may be somewhat specific to myself: I haven't made it all that generic, but just enough to do what I want it to do for me. And having done that, I even have trouble finding time to make more changes that *I* still want. Anyhow, if you want to see, it's currently running at http://digiweb.vaults.ca/digiweb/

Answer (score 0):

Both formats are reasonable date representations.  SQLite doesn't have a native datetime type, but rather has a number of functions for dealing with dates/times stored as reals, ints, or text objects (see http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Given that Django and Digicam choose to handle dates in different formats, your best route is probably to write a new model field type that can handle the date format used by Digikam (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/).  If all you're doing is reading the Digikam dtabase, this is pretty easy--you'll just have to code a bit to convert the representation into a Python Datetime object, which you'll probably be able to do using the Python's `datetime.strptime` function (http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: Hey, I liked the custom model field idea, so I tried writing a subclass of models.DateTimeField that overrode the to_python method and added a line the cleaned out the 'T'. However, this did not solve the problem. The error occurs earlier, in the db backend itself. SmileyChris on the django IRC channel advised me to try to patch or override the db backend itself. I'm going to try this now...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2): sqlite doesn't do any input validation as far as I know. Looking at the [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), I see this:

> SQLite does not have a storage class
>   set aside for storing dates and/or
>   times. Instead, the built-in Date And
>   Time Functions of SQLite are capable
>   of storing dates and times as TEXT,
>   REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> ...

So from my reading, Digikam is the one that's not playing by the (very soft) sqlite rules. (Probably because what you are describing was not in the authors' mind when they built their database).

Depending on your workflow for this, there are a few options I can think of, none very satisfying:

- modify the Digicam code to output something like the TEXT format for Date that SQLite advertises in its docs.

  modify the Django code to parse that date format.

  create a view in your database, using one of the [date manipulation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions to convert that column, and have django use that view

The first two are rather complex/hard to maintain, the third one seems doable without too much hassle.

A last workaround, if you're not actually using the same database (but a copy) for both apps is to write a simple script to convert that column wholesale. Not "pretty", but should work.